# Subversion and source not committed in Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, svn

I have installed the latest release of Subversion following these instructions http://www.drbob42.com/examines/examinD3.htm successfully. Then I installed the Delphi IDE integration too.

If I open a Delphi project, right click on the Project Manager in the Delphi IDE and choose "Tortoise SVN" and then "Repository browser" I can see all the files in my project in the local repository.

At that stage I added one instruction line in my application source, saved and then tried to commit. The SVN commit form shows up but it says "No files were changed since the last commit. There is nothing for TortoiseSVN to do here". As I just changed the source of my application I was expecting SVN showing that. Why isn't this happening ?

I chose the option cleanup and the error message says "Cleanup failed to process the following paths..... is not a working directory

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check out the files from the repository into a working directory, and then modify the files that are in that working directory. (You don't directly modify files in the repo.)

Use "File->Open from Version Control", and complete the dialog. It will check out the files into the folder you specify as "Destination" (which should **not** be your repository - it should be a separate directory!), and then you modify the files in that working directory and commit (check in) your changes to the repository.